# check login credentials and open form based on username C#

Tags: c#, forms, ms-access, authorization

I'm using this code to verify login information when a user login, which are not maximum of three users morning shift, evening shift, and manager.

I was different forms to open based on username. I mean:

- `MorningShift` opens `frmCashier`
- `EveningShift` opens `frmCashier3`
- `Manager` opens `frmAdmin`

How can I do that?

The username is selected in a combo box then a password is entered.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cmdText = "select Count(*) from Staff where Sname=@p1 and Spass=@p2";
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=|DataDirectory|\\crepeDB.accdb;"))
    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", comboBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox1.Text);  // Is this a variable or a textbox?
        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            var form1 = new frmCashier();
            form1.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            form1.Show();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the staff table in the database contain a `Shift` column?

Comment: well, no, it just contains these three records under SName, SPass                      (Morningshift, 1234 - evening shift, 5555 - manager, 9999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
Form form1;
if (result > 0)
{
    this.Hide();
    if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "MorningShift") {
        form1 = new frmCashier();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "EveningShift") {
        form1 = new frmCashier3();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.Text.ToLower() == "Manager") {
        form1 = new frmAdmin();
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("unknown user");
    }
    form1.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
    form1.Show();
}
```